# How do Android check permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions, cts

Im trying Android CTS.
I facing problem during android.permission.

```
02-05 15:57:27 I/192.168.90.48:5555:         
android.permission.cts.NoNetworkStatePermissionTest#testSecurityExceptionFromDns FAIL 
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at android.permission.cts.NoNetworkStatePermissionTest.testSecurityExceptionFromDns
(NoNetworkStatePermissionTest.java:174)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

In my guess, this test check permission. Program tries like below:

```
public void testSecurityExceptionFromDns() throws Exception {
    try {
        InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        fail();
    } catch (SecurityException expected) {
    }   
}
```

expected behavior is that program throws Security-exception because this Application have not
`android.permission.INTERNET`

but it can get InetAdress even though it has no permission.

How can I fix this situation?

I already check permissions such as /dev/socket

Can somebody tell me what is happening ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INTERNET` permission is checked in the kernel, so you might be using a kernel that doesn't have all Android patches. Assuming you have applied patches, you need to compile with  `CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK` to enable Internet permission checks. The checks require all processes that try to create sockets, etc. to be a member of the `inet` group (GID 3003).

Answer (score 0):

Add below permission on manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your reply. 
I solved this problem!!!!!!!!!. 
The root cause is from our device's kernel version. We using linux_kernel 2.6.34. 
Therefore, there are no CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK options and af_inet.c didnt define function that check the permision.

So I modify like below:

net/ipv4/af_inet.c

```
/* add ifdef CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK for CTS(android.permission) */
#ifdef CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK  
#include <linux/android_aid.h>
static inline int current_has_network(void)
{
    return in_egroup_p(AID_INET) || capable(CAP_NET_RAW);
}
#else
static inline int current_has_network(void)
{
    return 1;
}
#endif
/* end add */

static inline int current_has_network(void)
 {
    return in_egroup_p(AID_INET) || capable(CAP_NET_RAW);
int try_loading_module = 0;
int err;

if (!current_has_network()) // check permission
    return -EACCES;         // return if it has no permission 
 if (unlikely(!inet_ehash_secret))
if (sock->type != SOCK_RAW && sock->type != SOCK_DGRAM)
    build_ehash_secret();
```